# Temporarily assign an arbitrary value to a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Say I define a pointer to whatever type: `A* p`.
**I want to assign it later, but only with a condition that I know initially.**

#### Basic solution with a boolean

```cpp
A* p;
bool assign_p = condition; // initially
p = assign_p ? new A : NULL; // later
```

However, I would like to avoid using an extra variable (the boolean) in order to save space, as this process happens over large arrays. **My question is then: can I use the pointer as a temporary boolean?**

#### Solution with an arbitrary pointer value?

```cpp
A *p = condition ? (A*) 1 : NULL; // initially
A *p = p ? new A : NULL; // later
```

This uses only 1 variable (the pointer), but is it safe and good practice to assign `(A*) 1` even though it points nowhere?

#### Solution with an union?

```cpp
union boolA { bool assign; A* p; };
boolA P = {condition}; // initially
P.p = P.assign ? new A : NULL; // later
```

This should also use only the memory necessary for the pointer, and essentially does the same as the solution above, maybe in a better way?
But I am a bit confused concerning the undefined behaviors occurring with unions. Is it safe in this respect? Furthermore, is it a good practice to make arrays of unions if I need to have many of these pointers?

#### Other solution?

Comment: Why not just do *later* `A *p = condition ? new A : NULL; // later`

Comment: Why do you need `p` to exist (with any value, let alone an arbitrary one) before it is given a useful value?

Comment: @yeputons Not for this case  unions come with a lot of other issues. (std::variant in C++)

Comment: It would be nice to know why the downvotes. Anyways @NathanOliver-IsonStrike I do not know the condition later as this information is lost when I reach the assignment time.

Comment: @Peter I need p to exist before because it is shared between threads. If I define it later, it would be a different pointer for each thread.

Comment: @fffred   That's not true.  Initialising it to `nullptr` (on definition) allows all your threads to check before later using or reassigning it.   You don't need some arbitrary special "not null but not the result of a `new` expression either" value (and using one is just an opportunity for more errors).    If using the pointer from multiple threads [and one or more threads able to reassign it later] it will be necessary to synchronise access to avoid undefined behaviour, but having a "arbitrary" value doesn't change that (i.e. doesn't sidestep the need for synchronisation).

Comment: @Peter I am not sure I understand your point. If I always initialize `p` to `nullptr` I lose the information about whether I must assign it later or not. Note that only one thread will assign `p`, but several must read it, and this is synchronized of course).

Comment: @fffred  You're overcomplicating things.   The ONLY things you can do with a null pointer are (1) examine its value (e.g. `if (p != nullptr)` or (2) reassign it (e.g. `p = new A`) or (3) do nothing (leave it null).     Introducing another arbitrary pointer value to control if you reassign it offers no utility.   Either conditions are met to reassign it so it points at a valid object or they are not (in which case, leave it null).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be solved in a safe way by using a *sentinel* (an actual value that is interpreted in a special way, similar to how the number -1 is often used to indicate "not found" in search functions). Create a single instance of `A` (with its members set to arbitrary but safe values, e.g. all zeroes and nulls), store it as `A * sentinel`, and set the "true" array elements to `sentinel`. When you are ready to allocate the real objects, you can just compare the array elements to `sentinel`.

Answer (score 3):

Many systems will have no actual pointers with values lower than some cut-off (0x10000 for example), and you can therefore treat values above and below that cut-off in entirely different manners.

One example of this is windows, where values below the cut-off will be treated as resource values by many window-related functions, while values above that will be string pointers (either char or wchar_t depending on the function being invoked).

I see no problem with a function that treats 0, 1 and values above 0x10000 in entirely different ways.

Comment: Is that an example of UB?

Comment: Trying to dereference it would be UB, but in this scheme it's just being used as a value.

Comment: Consider no dereference. From that perspective is that possible that compiler would optimize the code in the assumption that these values are invalid?

Answer (score 0):

`sentinel` suggested earlier is a fine solution, but if you struggle to find such value for your object `A`, I think `std::optional<A*>` may also be a good solution for that. You can have three states -

- `std::nullopt` - The optional is not yet initialized
- `*opt = nullptr` - The optional has been initialized, but with `nullptr` (since the condition wasn't satisfied)
- `*opt = a` - The optional was initialized with a proper value (the condition is satisfied).

I think the main advantage is having different states for the first two options, which may be very useful for further logic you may need in the future, and for debugging purposes. It is also more clean than sentinel, since there's no "special value" the future reader\developer needs to remember\keep track of\check at every usage.

If `std::optional` is "heavy" for you, since you have lots of elements in the array etc, you can use `A**` as well, and have analog three cases (`ptr = nullptr`, `*ptr = nullptr`, `**ptr = a`).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am not sure how `std::optional` works internally, but I suspect it makes use of an additional variable. Is this what you mean by "heavy"?

Comment: Yes, you need to check the space of an instance of `std::optional` versus a simple pointer, and see what's the overhead. The double-pointer is an alternative approach with similar functionalities, but a bit less readable in my opinion.. Make your own considerations regarding which is more suitable.